# Rerender recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let take the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // get the list item
    MyListItemObject myListItemObject = getObject(i);

    //set some values
    viewHolder.prop1.setText(myListItemObject.prop1);
    viewHolder.prop2.setText(myListItemObject.prop2);

    //We got some setting from another object.
    if(externalObject.showProp2){
        viewHolder.prop2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        viewHolder.prop2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

By some external settings value we decide to show or hide `prop2` Now assume this value changes from `true` to `false`, how can I rerender the list. `notifyDatasetChanged()` will not work because it simply had not changed, only some external settings has.

Comment: Do you know the position of the row where the data has changed? specifically?

Comment: Al of them, as that external property has changed.

Comment: `notifyDatasetChanged()` should work. It simply redoes the `onBindViewHolder` and if your external setting is changed your view should reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `notifyDatasetChanged()`? According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()):

> This event does not specify what about the data set has changed, forcing any observers to assume that all existing items and structure may no longer be valid. LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views.

You would make the change to hide/show `prop2` in `onBindViewHolder()`. This should work for simple changes. If the external change cause a more involved layout change such as using a whole new view holder layout then a different approach may be in order.